# change color of button on click and push it into array using javascript

Tags: html, arrays, angularjs, css

I am trying to change color of button to see that button is selected. When button is select the value of button is push in to array. If I again click on selected button the selected button will become unselected and new color of button will be removed also this button's value is remove from array.
I have total 40 buttons. I made a demo.
Here is my Link

[JSFiddle snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/nw5ndzrt/82/)

```
function ctrl($scope) {
$scope.tooth=[];
var count=0;
$scope.setTooth = function(event,code) {

    if($scope.tooth.indexOf(code) > -1){
        alert("hiii");
        $scope.styleO = "styleOne";
        $scope.tooth.splice($scope.tooth.indexOf(code), 1);
        //$scope.tooth.push();
    }else{
         $scope.tooth[count]=code;
         alert("hello");
        $scope.styleT = "styleTwo";     
    }    
}
$scope.setQuadrantsTeeth = function(quadarent){

}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I will leave the pushing and splicing from array upto you.
But as far applying style 1 and 2 is concerned why don't you do this?

```
        $("button").click(function(){
         if($(this).hasClass("styleOne")){
          $(this).removeClass("styleOne");
          $(this).addClass("styleTwo");
         } else if($(this).hasClass("styleTwo")) {
          $(this).removeClass("styleTwo");
         } else if(!($(this).hasClass("styleTwo") || $(this).hasClass("styleOne"))){
          $(this).addClass("styleOne");
         }
        });
```